# How to increment and decrement a word in a file using any command-line in Windows e.g Python or any other windows based language/software

Tags: windows, python

For example: in a text file I want to do

```
text1
text2
text3
.
.
.
text100
text1
text2
text3
.
.
.
text100
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's pretty basic stuff in any script language. To learn something focus on one and learn the syntax mostly of a `for` loop.

As you're repeating the pattern `text1..100` you'll need to stack/nest two of them.

For demonstration purposes shorted to `text1..10`.

PowerShell

```
1..3|%{1..10|%{"text$_"}}
```

or

```
for($y=1;$y -le 3;$y++){for($x=1;$x -le 10;$x++){"text{0}" -f $x"}}
```

Batch cmd line

```
@for /l %y in (1,1,3) do @for /l %x in (1,1,10) Do @echo text%x
```

Batch file

```
@echo off
for /l %%y in (1,1,3) do for /l %%x in (1,1,10) Do echo text%%x
```

Python (I'm a noob here myself)

```
for y in range (1,4):
  for x in range (1,11):
    print("text#".replace('#',str(x)))
```

vbscript (cscript //NoLogo SU_1428257.vbs)

```
For y = 1 to 3
    For x = 1 to 10
        Wscript.Echo "text" & x
    Next
Next
```

I leave the redirection to a file up to you.

Comment: I recommend OP to use Python if they're going to learn one, since its cross platform, interactive, and generally thought to be easier to learn than C,Java, or command-line scripting languages.